# Problem with RSelenium when wrapping into function

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm running this code without problem:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

rd <- rsDriver(verbose   = FALSE,
               browser   = "chrome",
               chromever = "85.0.4183.83")

remDr <- rd$client
remDr$navigate("https://recruitcrm.io/jobs/Intellecta?1589280608414")
webElm <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "card-content")
page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>% html_nodes(".job-list-buttons") %>% html_text() %>% length()
```

When I wrap this code into a function and then use pmap from purrr to go throught the list of urls, elements and html nodes (url: https://recruitcrm.io/jobs/Intellecta?1589280608414, element: "card-content", nodes: ".job-list-button") I get this error:

```
Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".card\-content"}
```

I have few other websites that I map over without a problem.

**Edit**
Here is the code I run when I get the error message:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

scrape_selenium <- function(url, selector, click_action, heiti_vefsidu,  scroll, click) {

    rd <- rsDriver(verbose   = FALSE,
                   browser   = "chrome",
                   chromever = "85.0.4183.83")

    if (scroll) {

        remDr <- rd$client
        remDr$navigate(url)

        for(i in 1:20) {
            remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
            Sys.sleep(1)
        }

        page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

    } else if (click) {

        remDr <- rd$client
        remDr$navigate(url)
        webElm <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", click_action)

        for(i in 1:10) {
            webElm$clickElement()
            Sys.sleep(5)
        }

        page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

    } else {

        remDr <- rd$client
        remDr$navigate(url)
        webElm <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", click_action)
        page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

    }


    # 3.0 CREATE AND UPDATE DATA ----

    date_today <- today()
    fjoldi_auglysinga <- html(page_source[[1]]) %>% html_nodes(selector) %>% html_text() %>% length()

    data_tbl <- tibble(date    = date_today,
                       fjoldi  = fjoldi_auglysinga,
                       vefsida = heiti_vefsidu)


    # 4.0 Close broswer and stop the server ----

    remDr$close()
    rd$server$stop()
    gc()

    ## Stop didn't work so I found this solution:
    # https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/228
    system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)

    # 5.0 RETURN
    return(data_tbl)

}

url_list <- list(
    "https://kopavogur.alfred.is/",
    "https://atvinna.frettabladid.is/storf/",
    "https://www.alfred.is/starfsgrein/laus-storf",
    "https://recruitcrm.io/jobs/Intellecta?1589280608414"
)


selector_list <- list(
    "h5",
    ".hentry a",
    "h5",
    ".job-list-buttons"
)

click_list <- list(
    NULL,
    "load_more_jobs",
    NULL,
    "card-content"
)

heit_vefsidu <- list(
    "Kopavogur",
    "job_is",
    "Alfred",
    "Intellecta"
)

scroll <- list(
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    FALSE
)

click <- list(
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    FALSE
)



pmap(list(url_list, selector_list, click_list, heit_vefsidu, scroll, click), scrape_selenium)
```

Comment: Your code shows a different search than the error message:  `remDr$findElement(using = "class", "card-content")`, whereas the error message corresponds to `remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".card\\-content")`.

Comment: I know and I don't understand why. Here is the "element" list I'm mapping over:

click_list <- list(
    NULL,
    "load_more_jobs",
    NULL,
    "card-content"
)

There is no ".card\-content" as per the error message.

Comment: Show us the code you're running.  We can't debug it if we can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code.  I get the same error as you using your code outside the function as inside it.  I think the reason the message doesn't quite match your search is because RSelenium (or Selenium) translates the class name search into a CSS selector.  Apparently that class isn't always found:  you succeeded on your first try, but not later.  I never succeed.